# SSRS Pie Chart divide a slice

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following data:

```
1635057.    18  0   
1773006.    11  5   
1773020.    10  6   
1790079.    14  2   
1734013.    9   0   
1734015.    8   0   
1690039.    8   0   
1785007.    7   1   
1773004.    5   1
```

I want a SSRS PieCart where each slice is divided into two seperate slices
For example

1773004 would be red with 5 and 1 inside the slice.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you're asking here

Comment: 1773004 would be red with a label with both 5 & 1 in the text? Or two different slices, with size 1 and size 5?

Comment: 1773004 would be red with a label with both 5 & 1 in the the text in a single slice not two

Comment: You might want to look into a Sunburst Chart.

Comment: Draw a picture and update your question, it's difficult to understand what you are asking.